# confusion matrix and F1 score for an image classifier

Tags: python

hiya i followed this guide on how to make a powerfull image classifier with little data from 
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html
I need help on making a cofusion matrix and getting the F1 score of this code this is an image classifier that detects tumor the datasets are all grayscaled

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 140
nb_validation_samples = 40
epochs = 20
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

edit
now i got these codes

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 140
nb_validation_samples = 40
epochs = 2
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(test_datagen.samples / test_datagen.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)
print(cm)

model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

solved

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from PIL import ImageFile, Image
print(Image.__file__)
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\TRAIN'
validation_data_dir = r'C:\Users\Acer\imagerec\Brain\VAL'
nb_train_samples = 140
nb_validation_samples = 40
epochs = 2
batch_size = 5

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense

vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(), pooling='avg')
x = vgg.output
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(vgg.input, x)
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)
print(cm)

plt.imshow(cm)


model.save_weights('first_try.h5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code would do a confusion matrix and classification report for your validation generator

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predictions = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps=test_steps_per_epoch)
test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)
predicted_classes = numpy.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
true_classes = validation_generator.classes
class_labels = list(validation_generator.class_indices.keys())
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)   

cm=confusion_matrix(true_classes,predicted_classes)
print(cm)
```

to plot use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(cm)
```

Comment: hiya tnx for the reply is this as is or should i put something here? steps=test_steps_per_epoch

Comment: add this test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(test_data_generator.samples / test_data_generator.batch_size)

Comment: hiya while running my pc died and yeaaaa hahaha im still running it now

Comment: hiya I added this instead test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(test_datagen.samples / test_datagen.batch_size)

Comment: hiya and i got this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/condas/rawr.py", line 73, in <module>
    test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(test_datagen.samples / test_datagen.batch_size)
AttributeError: 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'samples'

Comment: btw thanks a bunch for the help I really appreciate it <3

Comment: i think its because there is no test_datagen.samples and test_datagen.batch_size only a test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

Comment: it should be test_steps_per_epoch = numpy.math.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size)

Comment: It was a confusion in the names

Comment: hiya thank you it works btw to plot this can i just do plt(cm)?